# Filter Stanford Dependency Parser Output

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

How can I modify this code to get only one particular output from the code. For example how can I get just `'nmod'` or `'dobj'` in output?

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tree import Tree
stanford_models = 'E:\stanford-parser\stanford-parser-3.7.0-models.jar'
stanford_jar = 'E:\stanford-parser\stanford-parser.jar'
st = StanfordDependencyParser(stanford_models, stanford_jar, encoding='utf-8')
text = 'Randy,Can you send me a schedule of the salary.'
result= st.raw_parse(text)
dep = result.__next__()
list(dep.triples())
```

The output is:

```
[(('send', 'VB'), 'discourse', ('Randy', 'UH')),
 (('send', 'VB'), 'aux', ('Can', 'MD')),
 (('send', 'VB'), 'nsubj', ('you', 'PRP')),
 (('send', 'VB'), 'iobj', ('me', 'PRP')),
 (('send', 'VB'), 'dobj', ('schedule', 'NN')),
 (('schedule', 'NN'), 'det', ('a', 'DT')),
 (('schedule', 'NN'), 'nmod', ('salary', 'NN')),
 (('salary', 'NN'), 'case', ('of', 'IN')),
 (('salary', 'NN'), 'det', ('the', 'DT'))]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you have to do is [`filter(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) and perhaps convert back to a `list(..)`:

```
the_triples = list(dep.triples()) #you already have this line
result = filter(lambda v : v[1] == 'nmod' or v[1] == 'dobj',the_triples)
```

When you run [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), `result` will be a list, if you work with [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), the result will be a *generator* (and thus processing is delayed until you really need the values). You can convert the generator to a list by calling `list(..)` on it.

[`filter(function,iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) takes as input a function and an iterable. As `iterable` we feed it the list of triples, as `function` we use `v : v[1] == 'nmod' or v[1] == 'dobj'` which is a function that takes the triple and succeeds given the second element of the triple is either `'nmod'` or `'dobj'`. So given the function evaluates the triple to `True`, the element will be emitted, otherwise it will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you. I changed 'result' to your code but I got this error: `'tuple' object has no attribute 'triples'`

Comment: @vsafa: well you should feed it he list of triples, I've updated the answer to make it more clear.